# Is "The Secret of Roan Inish" derived from a specific myth?

Tags: celtic, irish, scottish

In the wonderful John Sayles film [The Secret of Roan Inish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_of_Roan_Inish) (1994), the director presents a touching tale of a family with selkie connections.

The film was based on the the novel [Secret of the Ron Mor Skerry](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/rosalie-k-fry/secret-of-the-ron-mor-skerry/), by Rosalie K. Fry.

(Although the novel takes place in Scotland, while the film is set in Ireland, the location change wouldn't have presented a problem for the selkies, per the excellent swimming abilities;)

I know the film and book to be based on folktales in general, but are there specific stories from which it derives?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but here's a link with several other links to selkie tales: http://bestoflegends.org/fairy/selchies.html - "The seal-folk of Scotland and Ireland, variously called selchies, selkies, silkies, or roanes, have a habit of swimming out of the mists of Faery and landing on the shores of popular culture."